# Executing print inside exe from docker container

Tags: windows, docker

Program.exe is like:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hey, there!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Dockerfile is like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:2004
USER ContainerAdministrator
COPY Debug/. ./bin/
COPY log/. ./log/
RUN Powershell.exe -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe -OutFile 'c:\vc_redist.x86.exe' ; Start-Process c:\vc_redist.x86.exe -ArgumentList '/passive' -RedirectStandardOutput 'c:\Windows\System32' -Wait ; Remove-Item c:\vc_redist.x86.exe -Force
```

When I run the container and navigate to C:/bin to execute Program.exe, nothing is printed to console and Program.exe exits without error.
All DLLs and Libs that Program.exe depends on are ok ( verified with procmon and dependency walker ) and vcredist is correctly installed.

```
docker logs
```

command logs nothing.

Program.exe executes fine in host.

How to printf to console in this case?

Answer (score -1):

RUN is executed when the image is build not when the container is running use ENTRYPOINT or CMD. Have a look at the best pratice [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:2004
USER ContainerAdministrator
COPY Debug/. ./bin/
COPY log/. ./log/
RUN Powershell.exe -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe -OutFile 'c:\vc_redist.x86.exe' ; Start-Process c:\vc_redist.x86.exe -ArgumentList '/passive' -RedirectStandardOutput 'c:\Windows\System32' -Wait ; Remove-Item c:\vc_redist.x86.exe -Force
CMD C:/bin/Program.exe
```

You can use ENTRYPOINT to set the main command and use CMD to set default options like this to follow best pratices

```
ENTRYPOINT ["command"]
CMD ["param", "param"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Tested with ENTRYPOINT but same result 

Comment: sorry I am not familiar with Windows container, I didn't see you want to run Program.exe. How do you execute it with docker exec ?

Comment: docker run -it test powershell